# Decimal number Regular expression including +, - sign

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, decimalformat

I need a regular expression that validates a decimal number which includes +, - sign as well. For Example:

> +.12
>
> -0.13
>
> 0.+
>
> 45.-

But following are invalid Decimal numbers :

> +-0.12
>
> +99.+2
>
> 0.-12

Comment: Whay are `0.+`, `45.-` valid?

Comment: ^(\+|-)?(\d*.\d*)(\+|-)?$ try this

Comment: @dharmesh `#` passes. As does `k`. Or `@`.

Comment: @dharmesh Use character groups instead of alternation, you wouldn't believe how much of a difference (in speed) that makes... also you should escape the `.`.

Comment: How is 0.+ and 45.- valid decimal numbers? @arvind

Comment: I know 0.+ is  not a valid decimal number but it is my requirement to basically treat it as a valid entry @RanojitBanerjee

Comment: @dharmesh yes it  is working fine in all the cases I have checked so far....and one last thing that it treats + as a special character and prints the value %2B in place of +. What can I do for that ?

Comment: @Arvind i'm not sure which language you using this regular expression try 'new RegExp(//g);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`/^[-+]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)?\.\d*[+-]?$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/iD1uM7/1)

Flags: "g" (global) matches the entire regex as many times as it can. "m" (multiline) matches the start and end of a line with `^` and `$`.

- `^` Start of line.
- `[-+]?` Characters "+" or "-". The question mark means the previous part can be skipped if it can't be matched.
- `(?:0|[1-9]\d*)?` Matches either: "0", or >= 1.
- `\.` Literal dot "."
- `\d*` Zero or more digits (0 - 9).
- `[+-]?` Characters "+" or "-" (optional).
- `$` End of line.